# JSONB Column not mapping to JsonDocuent property type when scaffolding db

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, scaffolding

I cannot find any information for scaffolding a table which has a a JSONB column which should map to JsonDocument type property but instead maps to a string.

It is not an easily maintainable solution to have to manually replace every JSONB => string to JsonDocument.

Is there something I can do with the column type or maybe with the scaffold command to make JSONB columns automatically map to JsonDocument.

Database is POSTGRES and I'm using EntityframeworkCore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL JSONB columns are scaffolded as .NET string properties - there's no easy way to change that at the moment. There are plans for more extensibility/customizability at the EF Core scaffolding level (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4038), but at the moment you're going to have to change the CLR type yourself.

Comment: This seems to be scaffolded correctly now (ef core 7, 2023).  I ran into another issue, which is that the column isn't actually populated when reading from the db.